# AVG , group by, WHERE AVG greater (>) issue

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, average

this is my database

```
CREATE TABLE korisnici(
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(65,2)
    );

INSERT INTO korisnici VALUES 
("Marina",20.10),
("Petar",300.50),
("Ivana",100.70),
("Tomislav",50.20),
("Ivana",80.60),
("Petar",10.40),
("Marina",80.50),
("Ivana",70.50),
("Marina",130.20),
("Robert",60.20),
("Blanka",130.20),
("Blanka",220.40),
("Tomislav",150.20);
```

I would like to fetch all names from list which has average ammount of all their amounts greater than 150. Something like I tried

```
SELECT name, AVG(amount) AS avg FROM `korisnici` WHERE avg > 150 GROUP BY name
```

However my query fails, with error "Unknown column 'avg' in 'where clause'". Can someone give me a hint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use a column alias in a `WHERE`, `JOIN`, or `HAVING` clause, so you need to repeat the expression, but that's not the only problem.  When filtering on the result of an aggregation, the `HAVING` clause should be used instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT name, AVG(amount) AS avg 
FROM `korisnici` 
GROUP BY name
HAVING AVG(amount) > 150
```

The reason is that the `WHERE` clause is applied *before* the grouping and aggregation (and is used to determine *which* records get grouped and aggregated), while `HAVING` is applied *after* the aggregation.

Comment: Yes, that fixes the *query*, but most DBs won't let you refer to a column alias in the having/where clause - you have to repeat the expression. That's the *actual* cause of the error *`Unknown column 'avg' in 'where clause'`*

Comment: @Bohemian Most might not, but given that MySQL does, I can't quite fathom your point

Comment: @Strawberry My point is, just moving the condition to a HAVING clause will not fix the error in most dbs; you have to *also* use the raw expression in the condition (and not its alias). I don't know what relevance mysql has here.

Comment: @Bohemian I don't know either. I must have imagined it!!

Comment: @Bohemian _Just_ changing the `WHERE` clause to use the expression would have resulted in a syntactically proper query but not the proper results.  I have clarified that in my answer.

Answer (score -4):

You can not write like that: it is a common SQL error.

avg is the identifier and you can not use an identifier in the where clause..

```
    SELECT name, AVG(amount) AS avg 
    FROM `korisnici` 
    WHERE AVG(amount) > 150 GROUP BY name;
```

There you go..