# Using AVG with HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, average, having

I looked at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574707/avg-group-by-where-avg-greater-issue) and read the documentation on the [average function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg), but when I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
id      INT,
score   INT
);

INSERT INTO tab VALUES
(1, 22),
(2, 45),
(3, 82),
(4, 87);

SELECT score,AVG(score)
FROM tab 
GROUP BY score 
HAVING score>AVG(score)
```

which puts `AVG` after `score`, I get

> There are no results to be displayed.

How can I get this to work?

Here's the [fiddle](https://%3E%20https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwwvVhYFKu5VGTWR6YVjnZ/1).

Comment: Remove the HAVING clause, and you will see that this does not actually calculate the average as you intended to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're aggregating per "*score*". Doing such operation will bring you the average among one value for each record, hence being `AVG(score) = score` always.

You need to use the corresponding window function for that purpose ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwwvVhYFKu5VGTWR6YVjnZ/2)):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT score, AVG(score) OVER() AS average_score
    FROM tab 
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE score > average_score
```

or if you don't mind not selecting the average in your final output ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwwvVhYFKu5VGTWR6YVjnZ/3)):

```
SELECT score
FROM tab
WHERE score > (SELECT AVG(score) FROM tab)
```